# update but does not remove image from folder i have tried in seprate file too but doesnot work

Tags: php, mysqli

`this is my new index.php file

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `img_table`(`name`, `imgtitle`) 
               VALUES ('$name','$image')";
    header("location:fetch.php");
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"image/$image");
    }


}

?>
<html>
<head><title>hi</title></head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table border=1px;>
        <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <th>img_title</th>
        <td><input type="file" name="imgtitle"/>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add"/>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

`this is my db.php page

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root", "","crud");
if($con){
    echo "connected successfully";
}

?>
```

`this is my index.php page`

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $sname = $_POST['surname'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `surname`, `city`, `state`, `image`) 
               VALUES ('$name','$sname','$city','$state','$image')";
    header("location:fetch.php");
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"image/$image");
    }


}

?>



<html>
    <head>
    <title> crud operation </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table border=1px; solid;>
        <form method = "POST" action = "" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <label> name </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "name"/><br>

            <label> Surname </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "surname"/><br>

            <label> city </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "city"/><br>

            <label> state </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "state"/><br>

            <label> image </image>
            <input type= "file" name = "image"/>

            <tr>
            <td><input type = "submit" name= "submit" value="upload"/></td>
            </tr>

        </form>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

this is my fetch.php

```
<?php 
include('db.php');
?>

<html>
<table align = "center" border = 1px; >
    <tr><th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>surname</th>
        <th>city</th>
        <th>state</th>
        <th>image</th>
        <th colspan = "2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $query ="SELECT * FROM `table`";

        $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("could not fetch". mysqli_error($con));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fire))
        {   
    ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['surname'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['city'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['state'];?></td>

            <td><img = src = "image/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" style="width:100px; height:100px;" > </td>
            <td><a href ='update.php? id=<?php echo $row['id']?> &name=<?php echo $row['name']?> &sname=<?php echo $row['surname']?>&city=<?php echo $row['city']?>
                                      &state=<?php echo $row['state']?>
                                      &image=<?php echo $row['image']?>
                                     '/> EDIT </a></td>

            <td> <a href ='delete.php? id=<?php echo $row['id']?>'/>DELETE</a></td> 

        </tr>


    <?php } ?>
        </table>
        </html>
```

This is my update.php page problem is image is successfully update but not remove old image from folder.

```
 <?php
        include('db.php');
        if(isset($_POST['UPDATE']))
        {   
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $surname = $_REQUEST['sname'];
        $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
        $state = $_REQUEST['state'];
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

        $query = "UPDATE `table` SET `name`='$name' ,`surname`='$surname' ,
                 `city`='$city',`state`='$state',`image`='$image'  WHERE id = '$id' ";
            $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"image/$image");
            unlink('image/$image');
            header('location:fetch.php');

        }
        ?>

         <html>
            <head>
            <title> crud operation </title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <table  border=1px:solid;>
                <form  method = "POST" action = "#" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                    <label> name </label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "name" value = <?php echo "$_REQUEST[name]";?> /> <br>

                    <label> Surname </label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "surname" value = <?php echo "$_REQUEST[sname]";?> /><br>

                    <label> city </label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "city" value= <?php echo "$_REQUEST[city]";?> /><br>

                    <label> state </label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "state" value= <?php echo "$_REQUEST[state]";?> /><br>

                    <label> image </image>
                    <input type= "file" name = "image" value= <?php echo "$_REQUEST[image]";?> /><br>

                    <tr>
                    <td><input type = "submit" name= "UPDATE" value="UPDATE"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </form>
                </table>
            </body>

        </html>
```

i want to remove old image from folder when i update any image from table. but this code only update file in database as well as save new image in folder but does not remove old image from folder as i am beginner and here i know experts are available who make me understand whats wrong with my my code and suggest some better codes. please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code where i have updated some code, specially i have new add hidden field old image and then fetch that value and delete on one condition of image is uploaded at time edit or not.
Also please change table in query because we can not use table name `table` because it is reserved keyword.

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['UPDATE']))
    {   
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $surname = $_REQUEST['sname'];
    $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
    $state = $_REQUEST['state'];

    print_r($_FILES);
    //check new image is upload
    if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '' ){

        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"image/$image");
        unlink('image/'.$_POST['old_image']);
    }
    else{
        $image = $_POST['old_image'];
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `user` SET `name`='$name' ,`surname`='$surname' ,
             `city`='$city',`state`='$state',`image`='$image'  WHERE id = '$id' ";
        $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        header('location:fetch.php');

    }
    ?>

     <html>
        <head>
        <title> crud operation </title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <table  border=1px:solid;>
            <form  method = "POST" action = "#" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                <label> name </label>
                <input type = "text" name = "name" value = <?php echo "$_REQUEST[name]";?> /> <br>

                <label> Surname </label>
                <input type = "text" name = "surname" value = <?php echo "$_REQUEST[sname]";?> /><br>

                <label> city </label>
                <input type = "text" name = "city" value= <?php echo "$_REQUEST[city]";?> /><br>

                <label> state </label>
                <input type = "text" name = "state" value= <?php echo "$_REQUEST[state]";?> /><br>

                <label> image </image>
                <input type= "hidden" name = "old_image" value= <?php echo "$_REQUEST[image]";?> /><br>        
                <input type= "file" name = "image"  /><br>

                <tr>
                <td><input type = "submit" name= "UPDATE" value="UPDATE"/></td>
                </tr>

            </form>
            </table>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: its all because of your help.